# d3: How to get stacked graph to zoom?

Tags: javascript, d3.js

I have a stacked bar and line graph with a smaller area graph underneath to provide a timeline to do brush zooming with. I can make the brush affect the line, but not the stacked bars, when doing a brush zoom.

My line graph is declared as such:

```
var cumulativeLine = d3.line()
                    .x(function(d) { return (x(d.x1) + x(d.x0))/2; })
                    .y(function(d) { return y1(d.remainingCumulative); });
```

Whereas I have no equivalent for my stacked bars (which are generated from histogram data). To draw them, this is what I have:

```
svg2.append("g")
                .selectAll("g")
                .data(stack(stackData))
                .enter().append("g")
                .attr("fill", function(d) { return colours(d.key); })
                .selectAll("rect")
                .data(function(d) { return d; })
                .enter().append("rect")
                .attr('class', 'data-rect')
                .transition(t)
                .attr("x", 1)
                .attr("transform", function(d) { // transforming is way better looking than setting explicit x and y props.
                    return 'translate('+ x(d.data.x0) + ',' + y(d[1]) + ')';
                })
                .attr("height", function(d) { return y(d[0]) - y(d[1]); })
                .attr("width", function(d) { return (x(d.data.x1) - x(d.data.x0)) - 1; });
```

...where `svg2` is a canvas selection. This is the brushed function:

```
function brushed() {
                    if (d3.event.sourceEvent && d3.event.sourceEvent.type === "zoom") return; // ignore brush-by-zoom
                    var s = d3.event.selection || xZoom.range();
                    x.domain(s.map(xZoom.invert, xZoom));
                    svg2.selectAll(".data-rect").attr("d", function(d) {
                        //console.log(d); // low, high, data
                        return 
                    });
                    svg2.select(".firstline").attr("d", cumulativeLine);
                    svg2.select(".xAxis").call(d3.axisBottom(x));
                    svg.select(".zoom").call(zoom.transform, d3.zoomIdentity
                        .scale(width / (s[1] - s[0]))
                        .translate(-s[0], 0));
                }
```

My line is re-rendered mostly fine (it has margin overlap, but that's not my biggest issue right now) with the `.firstline` line, since I can give it a pre-made function. My question is; how can I provide the same for my stacked bars? A fuller example of my stacked bar rendering (with no line) [is here](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/VpKVGL?editors=0010).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Took me a while to realise that all I'm doing when moving the brush is moving the rects. And what controls the rects' position? The `transform` attribute. So I took the same transform call from the rect drawing part of my code and put it in the brush code, and voila, it works. So my final `brushed` function looks like this:

```
function brushed() {
                    if (d3.event.sourceEvent && d3.event.sourceEvent.type === "zoom") return; // ignore brush-by-zoom
                    var s = d3.event.selection || xZoom.range();
                    x.domain(s.map(xZoom.invert, xZoom));
                    svg2.selectAll(".data-rect").attr("transform", function(d) { 
                        return 'translate('+ x(d.data.x0) + ',' + y(d[1]) + ')';
                    })
                    svg2.select(".firstline").attr("d", cumulativeLine);
                    svg2.select(".xAxis").call(d3.axisBottom(x));
                    svg.select(".zoom").call(zoom.transform, d3.zoomIdentity
                        .scale(width / (s[1] - s[0]))
                        .translate(-s[0], 0));
                }
```

Comment: Do you have working example of stacked bar chart with brush effect